# Error using Nuget to install ServiceStack into a Visual Studio 2015 Solution

Tags: nuget, servicestack, umbraco, nuget-package, umbraco-ucommerce

I am trying to use Nuget to install ServiceStack ( https://servicestack.net/ ) into a Visual Studio 2015 C# Umbraco UCommerce web solution and I am getting the error below.  Any assistance to understand or resolve this would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Terry Clancy

ClanceZ

```
Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'ServiceStack.4.0.46' with respect to project 'TeraTastic03', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'ServiceStack.4.0.46' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'ServiceStack.4.0.46'
Resolved actions to install package 'ServiceStack.4.0.46'
Adding package 'ServiceStack.Interfaces.4.0.46' to folder 'C:\Clancy\A_TeraTastic\Dev\TeraTastic03\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.Interfaces.4.0.46' to folder 'C:\Clancy\A_TeraTastic\Dev\TeraTastic03\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.Interfaces.4.0.46' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'ServiceStack.Interfaces 4.0.46' to TeraTastic03
Adding package 'ServiceStack.Text.4.0.46' to folder 'C:\Clancy\A_TeraTastic\Dev\TeraTastic03\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.Text.4.0.46' to folder 'C:\Clancy\A_TeraTastic\Dev\TeraTastic03\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.Text.4.0.46' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'ServiceStack.Text 4.0.46' to TeraTastic03
Adding package 'ServiceStack.Client.4.0.46' to folder 'C:\Clancy\A_TeraTastic\Dev\TeraTastic03\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.Client.4.0.46' to folder 'C:\Clancy\A_TeraTastic\Dev\TeraTastic03\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.Client.4.0.46' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'ServiceStack.Client 4.0.46' to TeraTastic03
Adding package 'ServiceStack.Common.4.0.46' to folder 'C:\Clancy\A_TeraTastic\Dev\TeraTastic03\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.Common.4.0.46' to folder 'C:\Clancy\A_TeraTastic\Dev\TeraTastic03\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.Common.4.0.46' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'ServiceStack.Common 4.0.46' to TeraTastic03
Adding package 'ServiceStack.4.0.46' to folder 'C:\Clancy\A_TeraTastic\Dev\TeraTastic03\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.4.0.46' to folder 'C:\Clancy\A_TeraTastic\Dev\TeraTastic03\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.4.0.46' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'ServiceStack 4.0.46' to TeraTastic03

Install failed. Rolling back...

Removed package 'ServiceStack 4.0.46' from 'packages.config'
Removed package 'ServiceStack.Common 4.0.46' from 'packages.config'
Removed package 'ServiceStack.Client 4.0.46' from 'packages.config'
Removed package 'ServiceStack.Text 4.0.46' from 'packages.config'
Removed package 'ServiceStack.Interfaces 4.0.46' from 'packages.config'
Removing package 'ServiceStack 4.0.46' from folder 'C:\Clancy\A_TeraTastic\Dev\TeraTastic03\packages'
Removed package 'ServiceStack 4.0.46' from folder 'C:\Clancy\A_TeraTastic\Dev\TeraTastic03\packages'
Removing package 'ServiceStack.Common 4.0.46' from folder 'C:\Clancy\A_TeraTastic\Dev\TeraTastic03\packages'
Removed package 'ServiceStack.Common 4.0.46' from folder 'C:\Clancy\A_TeraTastic\Dev\TeraTastic03\packages'
Removing package 'ServiceStack.Client 4.0.46' from folder 'C:\Clancy\A_TeraTastic\Dev\TeraTastic03\packages'
Removed package 'ServiceStack.Client 4.0.46' from folder 'C:\Clancy\A_TeraTastic\Dev\TeraTastic03\packages'
Removing package 'ServiceStack.Text 4.0.46' from folder 'C:\Clancy\A_TeraTastic\Dev\TeraTastic03\packages'
Removed package 'ServiceStack.Text 4.0.46' from folder 'C:\Clancy\A_TeraTastic\Dev\TeraTastic03\packages'
Removing package 'ServiceStack.Interfaces 4.0.46' from folder 'C:\Clancy\A_TeraTastic\Dev\TeraTastic03\packages'
Removed package 'ServiceStack.Interfaces 4.0.46' from folder 'C:\Clancy\A_TeraTastic\Dev\TeraTastic03\packages'
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.AssemblyBinding.Parse(XContainer dependentAssembly)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.BindingRedirectManager.<>c.<GetAssemblyBindings>b__18_0(XElement dependentAssemblyElement)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Lookup`2.Create[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.BindingRedirectManager.GetAssemblyBindings(XDocument document)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.BindingRedirectManager.AddBindingRedirects(IEnumerable`1 bindingRedirects)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.RuntimeHelpers.<AddBindingRedirectsAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.RuntimeHelpers.<AddBindingRedirectsAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.RuntimeHelpers.<AddBindingRedirectsAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.VSMSBuildNuGetProjectSystem.<<AddBindingRedirects>b__59_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.VSMSBuildNuGetProjectSystem.AddBindingRedirects()
   at NuGet.ProjectManagement.MSBuildNuGetProject.PostProcessAsync(INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, CancellationToken token)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync>d__42.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync>d__42.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.<ExecuteActionsAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.<PerformActionAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
========== Finished ==========
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen this error before but the thing that's different about [ServiceStack.Interfaces](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Interfaces) is that it's a Signed PCL .dll.

You can try updating NuGet, or maybe just try installing ServiceStack.Interfaces package on its own:

```
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.Interfaces
```